# SqlDataSource COntrol modify during RUntime, I mean Changing it to another sqldatasource control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, controls, sqldatasource

I have 2 sqldatasource control which is SqlDataSource1 and SqlDataSource2.
At my Design page i make my Gridview bind to SqlDataSource1.

Is it possible to change the binding from 1 to 2 for the gridview? when I Click a button during runtime?

Comment: You can simply bind it from  code behind on button click. on buttonclick event do `gridView.DataSource = null;  gridView.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;  girdView.DataBind();`

Comment: What is issue you are facing. try to bind it with the existing SqlDatasource. As @prasy mentioned. Only you need to call `gridview.DataBind()` after assigning data source...

Comment: Oh, Thank you. Mean I just put gridView.DataSource =  SqlDataSource2.

Comment: But I Got THis Error , 
Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.
@prasy

Comment: But I Got THis Error , Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition. @sharpstudent

Comment: @WeakTaenie: place this code before binding the second datasource `gridview.DataSourceID=" ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before binding new SqlDataSource  at Runtime you should clear `DataSourceID` of the gridView. example:

```
gridView.DataSourceID = null;
gridView.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
gridView.DataBind();
```